# Windows 2019 Task Scheduler does not produce expected results id run after midnight

Tags: windows, scheduler, job-scheduling, windows-task-scheduler

In Windows Server 2019, I have created a task schedule to start a program to extract data for previous day and output to a file.  If the scheduled task runs anytime after midnight, the reports being output has zero records.  If the same jobs are scheduled to run before midnight the records are included in the extract.

**Note:** These same jobs were setup to run on Windows 2012 server Task Scheduler after midnight and there were no issues.

Task Security option are configured with the below settings enabled:
•   User Account: tested with local admin account and domain service ID added to local admin group
•   Run Whether user is logged on or not
•   Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources
•   Run with the highest privilege.
•   Configure for Windows 2019

Trigger setting configured as follows:
•   Daily @ 12:01 a.m.
•   Recur every 1 day

Actions setting configured as follows:
•   Program/Script: C:\XXXAutoReport\AutoReport.exe
•   Add arguments: 1

Additional settings enabled as follows:
•   Allow task to run on demand
•   Stops task if it runs longer that: 1 hour
•   If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop

Please advise what could be contributing to this and how to address.

Comment: every timestamp is both, before and after midnight ... The problem is obviously with your application and not the task scheduler. The task scheduler just starts the program. If it for certain points in time doesn't produce the expected results, you should debug your program

Comment: The Task Scheduler were setup previously on Windows 2012 Server and it ran successfully when run after midnight.  There were no changes to the application apart from installing on Windows 2019 Server and setting up the Task Scheduler the same as on Windows 2012.

Comment: Again: The task scheduler does nothing but starting *your* application. I don't know what information your application collects, but what happens if you start the application manually at 23:50 and 00:10? From where does your application gather the information?